# Finding Open Source Projects

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, cypress, open-source, test-script

This is bit of general question, How can SQA engineer find good open source projects for contribution. Actually, to be honest I want to know searching process and qualities of projects you usually see before contributing?

Comment: Welcome to the community. Your question isn't new and likely to be closed as a duplicate. Have you tried searching this site for other similar questions? Do these answer your question? https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1624/testing-in-open-source-projects or this one: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/25827/open-source-project-for-mobile-testing-practice 

We don't know enough about what you've done to find the answer or even what type of software you want to contribute to: web, mobile, API, security, etc